# How to paint on a pbr texture

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-baking, shader-nodes

Does anyone know how to paint on an image texture? I only want to paint the lower part of the building but because it is a pbr texture the marks gets replicated throughout the rest of the building. I have attached my nodes, texture paint attempt, and reference. Thanks[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your uv us too big and makes the texture tiling, you will have to create a new uv and uv the whole four sides of the building, after that using a new image as mask you will be able to paint on the bottom of it, the other texture (not the bricks) will have to be a new node like principled bsdf or similar.

Comment: Adding to what I commented before: check out this video for clearing it out.  https://youtu.be/HC6hHnSseXI  that is the general workflow, I can send you a demo file tomorrow if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I am attaching a file as an example.
[image]

Create a 2nd UV for the mask, the first UV is for the tiled texture, so you can scale it as you wish.
Mixing two PBR materials (or any materials) using black and white mask (another image texture).

[image]
sorry for the bad quality image